# Fantasy novel: dueling sorcerers and a damsel in distress

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to recall the title of a novel I once read. The publication date would probably be in the '80s or early '90s. I don't remember much that happened in it, which may be an accurate recollection.

Anyway, the main plot concerns two men, both of whom are sorcerers, if I recall correctly, and a woman. One of the sorcerors is the protagonist, and the woman is (or becomes) his love interest. The other sorcerer is the antagonist, and seems to have some kind of relation to the woman. She might be his daughter, niece, ward, or something like that. Anyway, the antagonist has the woman imprisoned in an underground cavern or something. The protagonist, who might be a guest of the antagonist, somehow discovers the woman and is able to communicate with her, but not to rescue her. She might be trapped behind an ice wall, a magical barrier, or something. As I recall the story ends with a magical confrontation between the two sorcerers.

> Of course, the protagonist defeats the antagonist and rescues the woman.

And no, it's not a movie called *Arabian Adventure*, which as I recall was much more fun than the novel in question.

Additional Info:

- I believe the cover was glossy with an illustration, but I don't recall any details of the illustration. It seemed to me to be a generic '80s/'90s fantasy cover. I'm pretty sure it was a paperback.
- I don't recall who the author was. If it was Terry Brooks or Lloyd Alexander, I believe I would have remembered it. It might possibly have been Piers Anthony, but I still believe I would have remembered if he were the author. However, it seems to me that the author was male.
- I don't recall any humor in the book. I'm not saying there wasn't any, but the overall tone was serious.
- I believe the final duel was face-to-face, or at least it ended up that way.
- I don't recall that there was anything particularly novel about the magic system.
- It seems to me that the protagonist used a kind of magic that caused physical shock to the antagonist, such as extremes of temperature or pressure.
- > I think the antagonist died, but with no visible wounds, and his body was not disintegrated.
- I know this is very vague, but I think *ice* was important, possibly related to the magic of the antagonist and/or the protagonist.
- I'm quite confident I read this book by mid-1993 at the latest.
- I don't remember any dragons, witches, goblins, trolls, elves, or dwarves.
- I don't remember any large battles or quests (of the trekking sort).
- There may have been more than three characters, but I only remember three.
- Most of the action, such as it was, seems to have taken place in and around (and under?) the antagonist's castle/tower/manse/house.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall any of the magic used in the conflict?  Was it an open blast-and-block battle or a subtle tricks-and-traps duel?  Any idea what the cover looked like?

Comment: I don't recall much about either. I think the duel was face-to-face, or at least it ended up that way. I don't remember much about the magic system, but the K.O. seems to have involved extremes of temperature or pressure physically exhausting the antagonist sorceror. I also don't recall much about the cover, except it seemed to have a glossy cover illustration typical of the era.

Comment: If it helps to identify the story, I believe the antagonist died, but without being noticeably wounded or disintegrated.

Comment: Please edit any new details into your post. Was it run-of-the-mill sorcery or was some novel magical system, such as mirrors, involved?

Comment: Based on the story you described I was also tending to think it was a male author. :)  Certainly I can't imagine most of the women authors I was reading writing a female character in a role like that...

Comment: Perhaps [The Crystal Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crystal_Palace_(novel))?

Comment: The description is a little different than how I remember it, but that might be it. It was written by a woman, but "Phyllis" is not a stereotypically female name. The cover seems promising. I did think the female character was trapped somehow, which I don't get from the description. I would have to learn a little bit more about it first.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I was thinking of a certain book as I read the description. I couldn't recall the title off the top of my head, but I knew it was the sequel to *Sorcerer's Son.* Then I saw your suggestion, which turns out to be the same book I remembered reading when it was new in paperback in the late 1980s. I recommend you post your idea as a more detailed Answer.

Comment: @Lorendiac, you are welcome to post it as an answer if you remember it well enough to fill in the necessary details.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think I still own a copy, but I haven't read it from cover to cover in over 30 years, and probably haven't even flipped through it to reread a few scenes in more than 20. If I posted an answer, I'd be drawing heavily upon the Wikipedia article and any online reviews I could find, instead of working from strong recollection of nitpicking details. Besides, I don't feel right about stealing your thunder by posting an answer that fleshes out a suggestion you made first. (I've long since reached the point where I don't really care how much "reputation" I have, anyway.)

Comment: I'll consider finding my copy and posting an answer later this week - I've got Christmas chores that need to get done first! - but if anyone remembers the book well enough to answer without having to reread it first, please don't stand on ceremony. :-)  Or if the OP can get hold of a copy and confirm it as the one he's looking for, we can close as a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45988/5930).

Comment: I'll look around and see if I can find a copy somewhere, Although, even if I do, it might take a bit for it to jog my memory.

Comment: @anglus: I would be surprised if a person named “Phyllis” *wasn't* female — is there a word missing from your comment?

Comment: @RLH Intellectually, I know that "Phyllis" is a female name. However, I'm not sure that I've known anyone personally by that name. I don't recall ever meeting anyone with that name, at least from my generation or younger, and I didn't grow up referring to people of older generations by their first names. So, even though I know intellectually that "Phyllis" is a female name, it still wouldn't make nearly as strong an impression on my mind as if her name had been "Amy" or "Jennifer", or even something very unusual, like "Poinsettia".

Comment: @Lorendiac, et. al., for various reasons I've decided to withdraw from participation in Stack Exchange.  Sorry, going to have to renege on writing that answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's fine. I was able to obtain a copy of *The Crystal Palace*, and am in the process of reading it. When I am done I will post an update or answer, unless Lorendiac or someone else wishes to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Enchantica: Wrath of the Ice Sorcerer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2238814.Wrath_Of_The_Ice_Sorcerer)...? This book was authored by Andrew Bill and published in 1988.

Comment: The timeframe seems right, and it has some keywords, but the title seems a bit dramatic and doesn't ring a bell. The cover is also unfamiliar. I'm sure it was a paperback. I don't recall any dragons or armies, or even a quest.